# How to configure XAMPP to list all files and directories, including index files?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, htaccess

I want to configure XAMPP to show all files and folders in a given directory, even index files. But when I browse to the directory, index.php is run automatically instead.

What settings can I use in the .htaccess file to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `DirectoryIndex disabled` to your .htaccess file. That'll prevent Apache from looking for default index documents when the client requests only a directory, without a filename.

See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) for more information on the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Also note you'll have to enable directory browsing, otherwise you'll get a "permission denied" error.